# Reliably importing CSV columns as "double"

Tags: r, double, read.csv

I am trying to import multiple CSV files in a for loop. Iteratively trying to solve the errors the code produced I go to the below to do this.

```
for (E in EDCODES) {
  Filename <- paste("$. Data/2. Liabilities/",
                    E, 
                    sep="")
  Framename <- gsub("\\..*",
                    "", 
                    E)
  assign(Framename,
         read.csv(Filename, 
                  header = TRUE,
                  sep = ",", 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  na.strings = c("\"ND", 
                                 "ND,5",
                                 "5\""),
                  colClasses = c("BAA35" = "double"),
                  encoding = "UTF-8",
                  quote = ""))}
```

First I realized that the code does not always recognize the most important column "BAA35" as numeric, so I added the colClasses argument. Then I realized that the data has multiple versions of "NA", so I added the na.strings argument. The most common NA value is "ND, 5", which contains the separator ",". So if I add the na.strings argument as defined above I get a lot of `EOF within quoted string` warnings. The others are also versions of "ND, [NUMBER]" or "ND, 4, [YYYY-MM]".

If I then try to treat that issue with the most common recommendation I could find, adding `quote = ""` I just end up with a `more columns than column names` issue.

The data has 78 columns, so I don't believe posting it here will display in a usable way.

Can somebody recommend any solution for how I can reliable import this column as a numeric value and have R recognize NAs in the data correctly?

I think the issue might be that the na.strings contain commas and in some cases the ND,5 is read as one column with ND and one with a 5 and in other cases it's seen as the na.string. Any way to tell R to not split "ND,5" into two columns?

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a couple of lines of a typical CSV file (which still causes your errors)? Preferably with the different NA values you're testing

Comment: For what you said, it's likely that your CSV is broken. The best way is to ask who provides it to send it to you a correct version without using the separator in the fields. A fix that I don't recommend is to open the file with an editor and replace all the `ND,5` strings with just `ND` (save a copy of it of course) and then try to read it again.

Comment: I am afraid asking the provider will not be possible here and instead I'll need to work with the data I have. I'll post a sample here in a moment.

Comment: *If* you are working in an environment with a full Unix-style shell/access to `sed` the easiest way would be to replace those strings via something `sed -e s/ND,5/ND/`; you could also do it in two passes with R but it would be slower. If you do something like this, however, you need to know that your file will *never* contain `ND` in one field a value of `5` in the next field (which would be indistinguishable from an `ND,5` entry without some very fancy logic) ...

Comment: Thank you! Sadly the data is mostly numeric and the NDs are just the NA fillers.

Comment: I think the issue might be that the na.strings contain commas and in some cases the ND,5 is read as one column with ND and one with a 5 and in other cases it's seen as the na.string. Any way to tell R to not split "ND,5" into two columns?

Comment: Is there any reliable way to tell in your data whether `ND,5` is in fact a single missing value rather than a missing value in one column followed by a 5 in the next column? If you can assume they are all single missing values then Ben Bolker's suggestion of a command line fix is almost certainly easiest and best.

Comment: Thank you Gregor! Yes. The NAs are always formatted "ND, [Some one digit number]" and there is no case in which ND would not be followed by ", [Some one digit number]".

Comment: Sorry, for being so daft on this, but how would I implement the sed in the R code?

Comment: You should still be able to create an artificial CSV with just a few rows and columns ([mcve]) which your code stumbles on with the issues you're experiencing.